# How do I get Cygwin xterm to use bash and not sh?

Tags: cygwin

Just updated cygwin to 1.7.28 on Windows 7.

Previously when starting X, the xterm would open with bash. For some reason it is now opening with sh?
What configuration changes do I need to make so that bash is the default shell again?
Not sure why this change happened.

The shortcut to open the xterm is the same as it was during my initial installation.

```
 C:\cygwin\bin\run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c /usr/bin/startxwin.exe
```

But it still starts with the default shell set to sh.
I don't understand what changed.

My passwd file is the same as it was before.

It appears that everything starts fine with the standard shortcuts, but the X and xterm startups are not sourcing /etc/profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xterm seems to need the /etc/shells file to be present to work.  Add an /etc/shells file with the following contents:

```
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/csh
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/bin/tcsh
/usr/bin/csh
/usr/bin/sh
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/tcsh
```

Chris

Comment: That did the trick Chris. This makes me wonder what else is missing from the update I did on cygwin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had /etc/shells already (upgraded from ??? to 1.7.29), might have been new with upgrade, but still didn't work (xterm running sh instead of bash). Changed permissions on bash to fix.

It was 700 changed to 755

```
chmod 755 /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Run following command to set bash as default shell.

```
set shell=C:/cygwin/bin/bash
```

Note path `C:/cygwin/bin/bash` may vary.

Comment: That's great. Usually I don't have to do that when I have installed cygwin. Where do I need to put this command so that Xterm defaults to bash?

Any clue Why has my cygwin install changed the default this time?

Answer (score 0):

(Removed answer regarding `/etc/passwd`)

I tried your command on my cygwin and got the same behavior, i.e. xterm loaded with `/bin/sh`.

However, if I simply ran startxwin.exe directly, I get an xterm loaded with `/bin/bash`.

Dunno if this works for you, but, worth a try.

Comment: I know the elementary, fundamental aspects of shell use.
Something is not happening in the installation. I don't know where to look in the cygwin installation to track down what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with sh launching, but managed a different workaround after having issues with /etc/shells

I also wanted to get rid of the default white /bin/sh xterm that startxwin.exe created.

It turns out there's a **.startxwinrc** that startxwin.exe sources, so I had it do this:

```
# Launch prettier xterms with bash
. ./.profile

# Exit the cruddy white xterm launched by startxwin
exit
```

The dot-space syntax above is equivalent to "source" in bash, but is more shell-independent.